# How to get a response when connecting to a MS Graph?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

For Office365 there is 1 login and 2 passwords. Stored in the $pass1 and $pass2 variables. One is valid, the other is not.
How can I quickly check these passwords for authenticity in PowerShell when connecting to MS Graph or Azure in PowerShell? To use the correct password later in the script.
I'm thinking of using passwords when connecting to the graph, but not connecting, but getting a response. Successful or unsuccessful.
I found a script, but it checks the password of the local domain where I am. How to adapt a script to check a password for Azure?

```
$cred = Get-Credential #Read credentials
 $username = $cred.username
 $password = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().password

 # Get current domain using logged-on user's credentials
 $CurrentDomain = "LDAP://" + ([ADSI]"").distinguishedName
 $domain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($CurrentDomain,$UserName,$Password)

if ($domain.name -eq $null)
{
 write-host "Authentication failed - please verify your username and password."
 exit #terminate the script.
}
else
{
 write-host "Successfully authenticated with domain $domain.name"
}
```

Comment: what type of account is this question for ? a service principal ? if so you can request a token and if it fails then you know it is the wrong password

Comment: For Azure account

Comment: you will need to clarify what you mean by user account, is it a user or an app registration ?

Comment: User registration

Comment: you will need to research how to request a token to Graph. unclear how you're planning to do automation on a user, seems like you have a misconception